# How to silence Django fixed default date error W161

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `DateField` which I want to apply a default value to that has the same day and month, but different year dependent on the current date:

```
q1_results_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Q1 financial results',
        default=datetime.datetime(
            datetime.datetime.now().year,
            3,
            calendar.monthrange(datetime.datetime.now().year, 3)[1]
        ),
        blank=False,
        null=True,
    )
```

This works as intended, however I get the following error:

```
q1_results_date: (fields.W161) Fixed default value provided.
HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. 
This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use 
`django.utils.timezone.now`
```

How can I silence this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that returns the date you want:

```
def default_q1_results_date():
    return datetime.datetime(
            datetime.datetime.now().year,
            3,
            calendar.monthrange(datetime.datetime.now().year, 3)[1]
    )
```

then use the function as the default:

```
q1_results_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Q1 financial results',
        default=default_q1_results_date,
        ...
)
```

At the moment, the default is calculated once when the models are loaded, and won't be updated. In your case, you'd only notice this at new year.